# JDBC vs psql interval rendering differences

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, ireport, postgresql

Using postgresql 9.1 with linux psql console and the windows pgadminIII the query:

```
select '2012-05-05 15:57:31-07'::timestamp with time zone - '2012-05-01 23:13:34-07'::timestamp with time zone;
```

renders the return as:

```
    ?column?     
-----------------
 3 days 16:43:57
(1 row)
```

However, the windows JDBC driver (specifically using jasperreport's ireport) renders this same query as:

```
    ?column?     
-----------------
 0 years 0 mons 3 days 16 hours 43 mins 57.00 secs
(1 row)
```

I've explored `to_char` and the [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) but cannot find a solution. Two questions:  First, how can I make the JDBC driver render the interval with the same formatting as pqsl?

Second, can I instead make both psql and JDBC render the result as:

```
88:43:57
```

where hours keep counting into the 100s as the interval grows (its a silly industry standard...)

Comment: Could you run the query: " show LC_TIME;" using both clients and show us the result?

Comment: @SzymonGuz all result in: `en_US.UTF-8` as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made myself a function that does what I need.  I'm all ears for suggestions, improvements, and optimizations.

```
create or replace function format_hours(started timestamp with time zone, stopped timestamp with time zone)
returns text as $$
declare
        epoch_interval integer := extract(epoch from stopped - started);
        hours integer   := floor(epoch_interval/3600);
        minutes integer := floor((epoch_interval-hours*3600)/60);
        seconds integer := floor((epoch_interval-hours*3600-minutes*60));
begin
      return hours::text || ':' ||
             to_char(minutes, 'FM00') || ':' ||
             to_char(seconds, 'FM00');
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1):

"First, how can I make the JDBC driver render the interval with the same formatting as pqsl?"
I think this question is not actually well-defined. An object of type `org.postgresql.util.PGInterval` does not have a format. Of course if you call toString() on it, then you'll get something. You'll get what iReport shows. So in a sense this is its default format. But really it *is* just a bunch of ints for year, month, day, hour, minute, and a double for seconds. It's not a formatted thing.

pgAdmin III does some magic to format it more nicely. But this magic isn't built in to the JDBC driver. Szymon's answer will certainly work. But... blech.

"Second, can I instead make both psql and JDBC render the result as: `88:43:57`"
You could put the logic into the .jrxml instead of Szymon's procedure. This would be better because... well... it wouldn't really be better. It would just be different. It would let you leave your SQL query unmodified by calculating this in the report:

```
$F{?column?}.getDays() * 24 + $F{?column?}.getHours()
+ ":" + $F{?column?}.getMinutes() + ":" + $F{?column?}.getSeconds()
```

That's not 100% correct. You need to truncate (round?) the seconds from a double to an int for your requirement. And to be completely generic you need to add in months and years, but maybe you don't really care about those. Anyway, you **could** do it like this. Caveat intervalor.

Comment: I like the .jrxml version... but is it amendable to include intervals that span months?  Or is my best bet to just go to the `extract('epoch', ...)` and integer math version of things?

Comment: That's an interesting interaction/conflict between `interval` and `month`. It seems to me that once the interval contains more than zero months, then you have lost your precision around days/hours/minutes/seconds. I'm not certain. But I would use epoch times and use integer math as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any standard function you could use, but you can always format it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION format_time(t INTERVAL) 
RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
DECLARE
    res TEXT;
BEGIN
    res = 24 * EXTRACT(day FROM t ) + EXTRACT(hour FROM t );
    res = res || ':';
    res = res || EXTRACT(minute FROM t);
    res = res || ':';
    res = res || EXTRACT(second FROM t);
    RETURN res;
END;
$$;
```

And you can use it like this:

```
SELECT format_time(
    '2012-05-05 15:57:31-07'::timestamp with time zone 
    - 
    '2012-05-01 23:13:34-07'::timestamp with time zone
);
```

Comment: Yeah... I was hoping to avoid that.  It seemed like its a reasonable thing to expect the JDBC driver to render the same as psql, but I guess you can never be sure with java.